# Django random value for Model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

So I am able to generate a random id using uuid
So far so good
But when I try to database i get same value

```
 def f():
    d = uuid4()
    str = d.hex
    return str[0:16]
```

---

```
class Q(models.Model):
  a = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  b = models.IntegerField(max_length=25)
  c = models.IntegerField(max_length=32 , default=0)
  d = models.ManyToManyField(Ans , related_name='aa')
  e = models.CharField(max_length=18 , default = f() ,unique=True )


class Ans(models.Model):
  sub = models.CharField(max_length=150) 


-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I'm inserting like this

```
def ins(request):
     t =random.randint(0, 1000)
     p = Q(a = t , b=0 , c=0)
     p.save()
     return HttpResponse('Saved')
```

Just curious what the hell is happening here

Side note: If I set `e.unique = False` I get 2-3 with the same e values before I get a new
UUID values

Comment: Just a side note: You should avoid naming a model/class "Q" because Django has [Q-objects for advanced queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). No real issue but it may be confusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not call the function that you are passing to `default`:

```
e = models.CharField(max_length=18, default=f, unique=True)
```

FYI, according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default), you should pass a value or a callable:

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.

Comment: Jesus Christ.Thanks. Next time I will pay more attention to documentation